# Error when manually entering a JDatePicker object?

Tags: java

Why is there an error when entering manually? The error occurs when you type in the field, and not when you drop down the calendar.

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.util.Calendar

```
public class WordWorker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale locale=new Locale("ru","RU");
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        UtilDateModel model=new UtilDateModel();
        Properties p=new Properties();
        p.put("text.today","Today");
        p.put("text.month","Month");
        p.put("text.year","Year");
        JDatePanelImpl datePanel=new JDatePanelImpl(model,p);
        JDatePickerImpl datePicker=new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel,new DateLabelFormatter());
        datePicker.setTextEditable(true);

        frame.add(datePicker,"Center");
        JButton jButton=new JButton("Кнопка");
        jButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(datePicker.getModel().getDay());
                System.out.println(datePicker.getModel().getMonth()+1);
                System.out.println(datePicker.getModel().getYear());
                System.out.println(datePicker.getModel().getValue());
            }
        });
        frame.add(jButton,"South");
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }
    private static class DateLabelFormatter extends JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter
    {
        private String datePattern="dd.MM.yyyy";
        private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter=new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern);

        @Override
        public Object stringToValue(String text) throws ParseException {
            return dateFormatter.parseObject(text);
        }

        @Override
        public String valueToString(Object value) throws ParseException {
            if (value!=null)
            {
                Calendar cal= (Calendar) value;
                return dateFormatter.format(cal.getTime());
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message is pritty clear. Add the complete stacktrace

Comment: use date object from the utils package not from the calendar package. Check imports for date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
        public Object stringToValue(String text) throws ParseException {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(dateFormatter.parse(text));
            return cal;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess  value in `Calendar cal= (Calendar) value;` is a `Date` not a `Calendar` object

So ist must be

```
Date date= (Date) value;
return dateFormatter.format(date);
```

or shorter

```
return dateFormatter.format((Date) value);
```

Comment: Can I use CalendarDateModel?